# Add test project to MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

My project is C# MVC5 with Entity Freamework 6.

I have added a test project to the solution.

The first test is just a simple sanity check to ensure all is connected etc, so it just instantiates a class which calls a stored procedure in the constructor.

However I'm having problems because the test project doesn't have an app.config file and EF wants this for the connection details etc.

I appreciate that the client project is the one whose config is used, but this kind of destroys part of the reason for testing as I also want to ensure that the configuration is correct.

Surely there is a way to tell the subject project to use its own config?

Unit test code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using MyNamespace.Classes;

namespace MyNamespace_Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MyTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var test = new MyClass(1, 2010, 2, 80000, 25000, 48);
            var a = test.Text1;
            var b = test.Text2;
            Assert.IsTrue(true); // not actually doing a useful test yet               
        }
    }
}
```

Error is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string named
>   'Entities' could be found in the application config file.

Comment: Add one and include the connection string in it.

Comment: There are other issues, e.g. provider details for EF in the app.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your test project is separated, you must have `app.config` and add your connection string there.

There are two possible ways to solve it:

- Write test code inside main project so that it can reuse the main
  project `web.config` file
- Do not use connection string inside `web.config`,
  store it outside

Hope it helps.

Comment: (comment no longer relevant)

Comment: Btw - how do I do that? There is no "Test class" in the dialog list when I choose "Add new"

Comment: you can create test class manually and add refence "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting". Or you can copy your generated test class to your main project